# ModelState is Valid when the Request Model is actually Invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding, modelstate

I'm trying to validate request model in POST request for API. But the `ModelState.IsValid` always shows valid no matter the model I sent in the request body is correct or not. Invalid request body as in I changed the field name or modified the field type of a particular attribute.

Here's the code:

*ValidateModelStateAttribute class:*

```
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

*Controller class:*

```
[HttpPost("Search")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchBook([FromBody]Book searchRequest)
{
    if (searchRequest!= null && !ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return new ObjectResult("Book!");
}
```

*Book Model class:*

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Book
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string BookId;
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string BookName;       
}
```

*In Startup.cs class:*

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
 {
     options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelStateAttribute));
 })
```

When I debugged in the `ValidateModelStateAttribute` class, `isValid` field is always true, and `key`is always empty.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I thought `BookId` and `BookName` are properties.. how should i change the code?

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with `netcoreapp2.1` web api, it works correctly. How did you send your request?

Comment: I just put the request body in the body section and set it as json/application.. I have to remove the `[required]` attribute because none of them are required.. would that be the reason why it is not working? it always shows `context.ModelState.IsValid` is true no matter how wrong the type is..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for model-binding in MVC to work (and JSON.NET, which is used behind-the-scenes for JSON bodies), your `BookId` and `BookName` members must be *properties*, but they're currently *fields*. Here's what it should look like:

```
public class Book
{
    [Required]
    public string BookId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

(I've also removed `DataContract`, `DataSerializable` and  `DataMember` as these shouldn't be needed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the `isValid` field is still `true` while I modified the request model into a wrong model such as changing `BookId` to `BookIdd`... And `keys` still shows null.. :(

Comment: I saw that `context.ActionArguments` has the request model I requested in the body, so should I manually do the validation in this class? Or model binder can actually do the validation by itself?

Comment: This approach should work as it is without having to do extra. Tao Zhou's confirmed on your question that it does work correctly (thanks Tao!) so a repro is a good next step.

Comment: I found a work around using fluent validation library.. But that library can only check the field name for me, not the field type.. Is the method you mention above able to validate field type? by the way, I am not using MVC.. Im using ASP.Net core for Web API.. Would that be the reason?